# 4 digits combination where one digit is odd and one even

Tags: combinatorics

Using multiplication principle, total number of combinations is $10\cdot10\cdot10\cdot10 = 10^4$. If I need to have one digit that's odd and one that's even number, independent of where they are located, I would imagine the number of combinations should be $5\cdot5\cdot10\cdot10$. Because we have two digits that can only be one of 5 variations, and two that can be one of 10 variations.  But instead it is $10^4-5^4-5^4$. How do I build intuition for this kind of problems?

Comment: Do you understand why there are $10^4 - 2 \cdot 5^4$ decimal strings which contain at least one even digit and at least one odd digit?

Comment: @N.F.Taussig Unfortunately no

Comment: The number $5\cdot 5\cdot 10\cdot 10$ is the number of all $4$-digit combinations where _first_ digit is, say, odd, the _second_ digit is, say, even, and the third and fourth digits are arbitrary. It should be self-evident that this is undercounting: there is a combination $5566$, say, which still has an odd digit and an even digit - but you did not count it above. Now, think of different ways how to account for _all_ combinations.

Comment: BTW a hint: which combinations do _not_ have at least one odd digit and at least one even digit? Maybe those are easier to count? (Answer: those which have _all digits even_ and those that have _all digits odd_.)